# Custom submit button callback overrides default callback?

Tags: forms

I am trying to accomplish the following functionality:

I have a [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) registration form to which I have added a custom form element (just a submit button) using `hook_form_alter()`.

The submit button has a `#submit` property set to a `custom_callback` function.

For debugging purposes, the callback function just displays a

```
drupal_set_message('hello world');
```

The general idea is that the button is used to gather information from a webservice (in the callback function) and then fill the form with the returned values.

The user can then check the values and submit the user registration form.

When I click the custom submit button, it fires the custom callback. But when I click the user register form submit button, it also fires the custom callback?

I have checked the dpm of $form and the `#submit` properties are as follows:

```
$form['#submit'][0] == de default (correct) user registration callback
$form['custom']['#submit'][0] == de custom submit handler
```

So, any clues on why the default submit handler no longer works?

**EDIT:**

My form alter implementation looks like this (just add an image button)

```
   $form['custom'] = array(
    '#name' => 'custom',
    '#type' => 'image_button',
    '#src' => drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/logo.png',
    '#value' => t('get data'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="button-wrapper">',
    '#attributes' => array('alt' => t('get data')),
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    //'#weight' => -99,
    '#submit' => array('custom_callback'),
  );
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also post your hook_form_alter code also in the question?

Comment: Of course no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems to be custom form element. Change it to :

```
$form['custom'] = array( 
    '#name' => 'custom', 
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('get data'), 
    '#prefix' => '<div class="button-wrapper">', 
    '#attributes' => array('alt' => t('get data')), 
    '#suffix' => '</div>', 
    '#submit' => array('custom_callback'), 
  );
```

Comment: I have tried your suggested solution, but the result is the same. Which makes sense I guess, since it was just another syntax of adding something to the array #submit

I want the 2 submit buttons to go to 2 different callbacks..

Thanks already though!

Comment: Remove #submit from the `custom` and add it to $form array.

Comment: and no need to add extra submit button actually.

Comment: If I would add it to $form['#submit'], how would I be able to distinct between the 2 buttons?

Could you also elaborate on the comment that I would not need 2 buttons?

(I need to have access to $form_state in my custom callback function)

Comment: You can call two submit callback from single existing button.

Comment: Check updated answer..

Comment: I tried it like this

  $form['custom']['#submit'] = array('custom_callback');

But no luck...
The #submit does not show in my dpm of $form now.

When i did it like posted in the question above, the submit handler was there, but he overruled all the others...

Comment: Add both function in array, you have added only `custom_callback`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19613/discussion-between-guardian-and-sumit-madan).